# Exist an way in vim where I can select a block of code, move exactly one word in every line and insert some text (at the end of the words)?

Tags: vim, vi

The first word of every line have different sizes, so it's not a uniform block. I tried control-v + G (end of the file) + w but this don't move the selection to the end of the words rather seems to take the average size of the words and move this amount.

Comment: An example of the data you're working with and an example of how you want it to
look after processing will help people answer the question for you. Since then
1) there is no ambiguity and 2) people can copy the examples and experiment
with it to build a good answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways (depends were you want to move these first words to). You
can populate a register with them like so:

1. clear a register with `qqq` (to clear the `q` register)
2. select the lines of interest
3. do the command`:'<,'>norm "Qyw` to apply the `norm`al mode commands to each
   line. Here we `y`ank each `w`ord into the `q` register, (capital `Q` means to
   append to the register, instead of overwriting it)
4. do `"qp` to paste the words where you want them

```
one (and some more text)
two (and some more text)
three (and some more text)
four (and some more text)
five (and some more text)
six (and some more text)
```

step 3) will paste the following:

```
 one two three four five six
```

Answer (score 0):

"Append arbitrary text after the first word of several lines" doesn't really imply *selecting* those first words.

Assuming you need to perform that task on the whole buffer, it is simply a matter of using `:help :normal` on every line:

```
:%normal! <motion>afoo<CR>
:%normal! <motion>ifoo<CR>
```

If you want to do it on the current "paragraph":

```
:'{,'}normal! <motion>afoo<CR>
:'{,'}normal! <motion>ifoo<CR>
```

or, if you don't like ranges:

```
vip:normal! <motion>afoo<CR>
vip:normal! <motion>ifoo<CR>
```

It can also be done very easily with a substitution.

But your wording is confusing: `(at the end of the words)` vs `w` which jumps to the beginning of a word, etc. so you might want to provide a realistic before/after sample.